# How renaming files from figures to letters

Tags: linux

would like to know the appropriate script to use rename these files:
2000.jpg
B001.jpg 
9002.jpg
5006.jpg
A007.jpg 
 to 
ICON000.jpg 
ICON001.jpg 
ICON002.jpg 
ICON006.jpg
would like to convert all letters plus figures to ICON.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep the last three numbers of your filenames and replace everything before them with the word ICON.

On Linux you can accomplish this with the `rename` command and its `perl` regular expressions.
Simply run the following command inside your image folder:

```
rename 's/^.*([0-9]{3}\.jpg)$/ICON$1/' *.jpg
```

Please note that different versions of `rename` may exist on your system. If the `rename` command above is not working for you, please take a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename